# react native: functions are not valid as a react child .This may happen if you return a component instead of a <component/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState("");

  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

  const goalInputHandler = enteredText => {
    setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
  };

  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    //console.log(enteredGoal);

    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [...currentGoals, enteredGoal]);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Course Goal"
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
          value={enteredGoal}
        />
        <Button title="Add" onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
      <View>{(courseGoals.map = goal => <Text key={goal}>{goal}</Text>)}</View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: 50
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  input: {
    width: "70%",
    borderBottomColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

please i have been battling with this error more than a week now.Any help will be appreciated.I am actually following a tutorial using expo to build react native app on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the question is, but

```
<View>{(courseGoals.map = goal => <Text key={goal}>{goal}</Text>)}</View>
```

should look like this

```
<View>{courseGoals.map(goal => <Text key={goal}>{goal}</Text>)}</View>
```

Comment: thanks a lot the i got it functioning with the assistance you render for me lol.Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `map` call, change it to this:

```
<View>{courseGoals.map(goal => <Text key={goal}>{goal}</Text>)}</View>
```

Otherwise what you're doing is trying to redefine `courseGoals.map`.